# Typescript 3.0.1 Compiler option typeRoots unrecognized

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile a basic project and include lodash in my libraries. According to the Typescript 3.0 documentation this should work.

package.json

```
{ 
 ...
 "dependencies": {
   "lodash": "4.17.10",
   "npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
   "typescript": "3.0.1"
  }
 ...
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The same thing happens for `types`. According to google searches, `typeRoots` or `types` is required for my components to include `lodash`. What am I missing?

Comment: 2.7.2 works fine

Comment: Did you try removing `typeRoots` and only include `"types" : ["node", "lodash"]`?

Comment: Yes, "types" results in the same error

Comment: Did you install the `@types/lodash` package?  It has to be installed separately from `lodash`.

Answer (score 0):

my answer:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "typeRoots": ["app/types/*","./node_modules/@types","../../node_modules/@types",],
     "types":["node","jest"],  
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators":true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames":true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization":false,
    "outDir": "build"

  },
  "include": ["./app/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./__tests__/*"]
}
```